# Generate new column in dataframe, based on group-event

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe with three groups (x: 1, 2, 3) and some events (0 and 1 in y):

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df

> df
  x y
1 1 0
2 1 0
3 1 1
4 2 0
5 2 0
6 3 0
7 3 0
8 3 0
9 3 1
```

Now i want to generate a new column z, based on the events in y: if there is any y = 1 in one group, the whole group should get a 1 for z; else NA. How can z be generated this way? df should look like:

```
> df
  x y  z
1 1 0  1
2 1 0  1
3 1 1  1
4 2 0 NA
5 2 0 NA
6 3 0  1
7 3 0  1
8 3 0  1
9 3 1  1
```

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: A data.table solution could be `setDT(df)[, z := if(any(y == 1)) 1, by = x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(z = ifelse(any(y == 1), 1, NA)) %>%
  data.frame()

#   x y  z
# 1 1 0  1
# 2 1 0  1
# 3 1 1  1
# 4 2 0 NA
# 5 2 0 NA
# 6 3 0  1
# 7 3 0  1
# 8 3 0  1
# 9 3 1  1
```